# Apple Id in appstore can't change

Tags: ios, macos, app-store

I recently bought a macbook from my friend.But in appstore his appole id is the registered one..I signout and again sign in with my id some apps can be updated but some others like xcode is still using the old id(my friends id).This id is uneditable in the textfield too.How can I remove his id and enter my id
 I thought to update the app using his password but that even not feasible solution I need to delete his account completly from All appstore app without knowing his credentials is there any way??

Answer (score 0):

Open *XCode -> Organizer -> Devices -> Provision Profiles (Under Library) -> Press refresh button*. This will ask for the apple Id so put in your credentials there and it should do the trick.

Comment: There is no provision profile option

Comment: Have you selected the *Devices* tab from the top icon…?

Comment: Yes I am using xcode5